# Как изменить размер background-image в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qss

Я пытался изменить размер изображения с помощью `qss`, но безуспешно.

```
QMainWindow#log{
    background-image: url(login_4k.jpg);
}
```

вот код

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQuick
import sys
import os
import pathlib
import PyQt5

class Login(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    switch_window = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 180)
        self.setWindowTitle('Login')
        self.setStyleSheet(open("style.qss", "r").read())
        self.setObjectName("log")

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(135, 100, 130, 40))
        self.button.setText("Login")
        self.verification_lane = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.verification_lane.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 50, 200, 30))
        self.verification_lane.returnPressed.connect(self.button.click)
        self.verification_lane.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_MacShowFocusRect, 0)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ls = Login()
    ls.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

размер изображения явно больше чем `400` на `180`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets  #,  QtQuick
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#import os
#import pathlib
#import PyQt5

class Login(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
#    switch_window = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
#        self.setFixedSize(400, 180)
        self.setWindowTitle('Login')
#        self.setObjectName("log")

# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.resize(400, 180)
        background = QPixmap("im.png").scaled(400, 180)              
        pal = self.palette()
        pal.setBrush(QPalette.Background, QBrush(background))
        self.setPalette(pal)
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(135, 100, 130, 40))
        self.button.setText("Login")
        self.verification_lane = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.verification_lane.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 50, 200, 30))
        self.verification_lane.returnPressed.connect(self.button.click)
        self.verification_lane.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_MacShowFocusRect, 0)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ls = Login()
    ls.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> Обязательно надо давать размер экрана через resize? Не хотелось бы , чтобы была возможность изменять размер окна курсором

Нет не обязательно. Делайте как вам надо.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets  #,  QtQuick
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Login(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
#    switch_window = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 180)
        self.setWindowTitle('Login')
#        self.setObjectName("log")

# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
#        self.resize(400, 180)
        background = QPixmap("im.png").scaled(400, 180)              
        pal = self.palette()
        pal.setBrush(QPalette.Background, QBrush(background))
        self.setPalette(pal)
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(135, 100, 130, 40))
        self.button.setText("Login")
        self.verification_lane = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.verification_lane.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 50, 200, 30))
        self.verification_lane.returnPressed.connect(self.button.click)
        self.verification_lane.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_MacShowFocusRect, 0)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ls = Login()
    ls.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Обязательно надо давать размер экрана через resize? Не хотелось бы , чтобы была возможность изменять размер окна курсором

Comment: @whyeaye Посмотрите обновление, я просто так сделал, чтобы вы увидели как но рисуется.